# Pascal fatal error ";" expected but else founded

Tags: windows, pascal, freepascal

```
uses crt;
var
     i: integer;
  stav: integer;
  prsten: boolean;

begin 
  clrscr();
  stav:=0;
  prsten:=false;
repeat
   case stav of
     0: begin  //Zacatek hry//
        writeln('Toto je hra, jsi Princ a jsi v lese.');
        writeln('Na krizovatce muzes jit doleva = 1, nebo doprava = 2');
        readln(stav);
       end;

     1: begin
         writeln('Potkas draka, ktery vezni krasnou princeznu. ');
         writeln('3 = Prepadnout draka, 4 = Promluvit s nim');
         readln(stav);
        end;

     2: begin
         writeln('Potkas pocestneho. ');
         writeln('5 = Pokracujes dal lesem, 6 = Promluvit s pocestnym');
         readln(stav);
        end;

     3: begin
         writeln('Drak je silnejsi nez Ty a tak te rozprasil na popel.');
         writeln('Zacni znovu stisknutim klavesy 0.');
         readln(stav);
        end;

     4: begin
         writeln('Drak Te vyzve na souboj, ale Ty na nej nejsi jeste pripraven.');
         writeln('Musis pokracovat dal lesem. Stiskni 5.');
         readln(stav);
        end;

     5: begin
         writeln('Po dlouhe a namahave ceste jsi dorazil do mistni knajpy.');
         writeln('Najis a napijes se a pokracujes dal. Kousek od knajpy   potkas         pocestneho');
         writeln('Promluvis s nim. Stiskni 6.');
         readln(stav);
        end;
     6: begin
         writeln('Povis mu, ze se pokousis zachranit princeznu pred drakem.');
         writeln('On se ti rozhodne pomoci a daruje Ti kouzelny prsten.');
         writeln('Nasadit prsten na ruku a pokracovat k drakovi 7 / Strcit prsten do    kapsy 8 a pokracovat k drakovi.');
         readln(stav);
        end;
     7: begin
         writeln('Prijdes k drakovi a das se s nim do boje.');
         writeln('Draka zabijes a muzes pokracovat k princezne.');
         writeln('Pokracovat k princezne, stiskni 9.');
         prsten:=true;
         readln(stav);
        end;
     8: begin
         writeln('Prijdes k drakovi a das se s nim do boje.');
         writeln('Draka zabijes a muzes pokracovat k princezne.');
         writeln('Pokracovat k princezne, stiskni 9.');
         readln(stav);
         prsten:=false;
        end;
     9: begin
         if prsten then

           writeln('Princeznu jsi uchvatil a muzes si ji odvest do hradu.');

         else

           wrtieln('Princezna je rada, ze jsi ji zachranil, ale opovrhuje Tebou.');

         readln(stav);
        end;
   end;
until stav<0;

writeln('KONEC');
readln;
end.
```

What is causing the `fatal error ";" expected but else founded` message?

Comment: You have a typo : wrtieln('Princezna je rada, ze jsi ji zachranil, ale opovrhuje Tebou.');

Comment: Thanks, but the error is still here.

Comment: What line is the error on? Your compiler will tell you...

Answer (score 4):

Unlike C, in Pascal a semicolon `;` **separates** statements, it does not terminate them, and the `then` clause requires a single statement. `then WriteLn(...); else` is two statements; you want `then WriteLn(...) else`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take this opportunity to learn how to read and use error messages to your advantage.

The compiler tells you exactly what the error is (it's a `;` before an `else`, because both of those are mentioned in the error message). It also gives you the exact line number where it's reporting the error; that's the number (usually in parentheses right before the error message, like (from Delphi):

> [DCC Error] Project2.dpr(14): E2153 ';' not allowed before 'ELSE'

So the error is happening on line 14 (in my code - your number will be different). Let's look at that line and a few before and after:

```
if prsten then
  writeln('Princeznu jsi uchvatil a muzes si ji odvest do hradu.');
else
  wrtieln('Princezna je rada, ze jsi ji zachranil, ale opovrhuje Tebou.');
```

So look at the error message:

> ';' not allowed before 'ELSE'

That clearly tells you that the `;` in the line before the `else` is the problem (that's very clear, because it says *not allowed*), so remove it.

BTW, now you're going to get another error:

> [DCC Error] Project2.dpr(15): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'wrtieln'

I think you should be able to figure that one out; again, the compiler gives you the exact line number.

You're going to get another one, if you've posted your entire code:

> [DCC Error] Project2.dpr(18): E2029 Statement expected but end of file found

This is because you've left out the `end.` that marks the end of a program file in Pascal. If you've not posted your entire code, you may not get it.

It's important to learn to *actually read the words* when you get an error message from the compiler. In most languages, the messages are clearly worded, and they *all* have information you can use to try to figure out (or at least narrow down) the problems in your code.

Comment: And googling "dangling else pascal" might also help.